# Domain requires KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the host BIOS

Tags: virtualization, kvm, bios, theforeman

Unable to power on VM from foreman.
I could create the VM but it gives me below error when trying to power on. I could see that the VM is created in host.
Failed to start abc.sdnlab.com: Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: unsupported configuration: Domain requires KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm modules.

I have checked that kvm kernel module is loaded. 
Any idea what can be done?

Comment: You do what it says: You enable virtualization in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check in BIOS and enable virtualization there ( I think it should be there under Security section).

The, do this to verify kvm module is loaded.
#lsmod | grep kvm

if kvm module is not loaded, you need to do #modprobe kvm

Check whether kvm is properly loaded, using #dmesg.

PS:
You may need to check whether libvirtd daemon is running. (For this you need to start, libvirtd daemon). 
I think it is "service libvirtd start"

Comment: In my case I just Enabled "Intel Visualization Technology" at BIOS -> ADVANCE->CPU->Intel Visualization Technology  . you can check the result by  "lsmod | grep kvm" before and after enabling

Comment: @sam Did you mean "Intel *Virtualization* Technology"?  Eg: `VT-x`

Answer (score 0):

I got fix for this issue : the details of the issue fix are as follows :

## KVM Software tools should be on the controller

patterns-sles-kvm_server - KVM Host Server   12-58.8

patterns-sles-kvm_server-32bit - KVM Host Server

patterns-sles-kvm_tools - KVM Virtualization Host and tools

patterns-sles-kvm_tools-32bit - KVM Virtualization Host and tools

qemu-kvm - Kernel-based Virtual Machine

virt-v2v - Convert a virtual machine to run on KVM

yast2-vm - Configure Hypervisor and Tools for Xen and KVM

## check the hardware requirement as mentioned below:

1.1. Hardware Requirements¶
Currently, SUSE only supports KVM full virtualization on x86_64 hosts. KVM is designed around hardware virtualization

features included in AMD (AMD-V) and Intel (VT-x) CPUs. It supports virtualization features of chipsets, and PCI devices,

such as an I/O Memory Mapping Unit (IOMMU) and Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)).

You can test whether your CPU supports hardware virtualization with the following command:

egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
If this command returns no output, your processor either does not support hardware virtualization, or this feature has been disabled in the BIOS.

The following Web site identifies processors which support hardware virtualization:

## how to enable the vx-t in virtual machine :

https://forum.ivorde.com/kvm-nested-in-vmware-esxi-5-5-enable-guest-hypervisor-vmx-svm-flags-without-vsphere-web-client-

t19773.html

GO to the VMS vmdk folders and edit .vmx file and add the following flag in that file and save it.

vhv.enable = "TRUE"

Follow the commands below to restart the VM and reboot the machine.

/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM # vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep -i sles
15     SLES-82                [datastore1] SLES 1/SLES 1.vmx                               sles11_64Guest   vmx-08
59     SLES 12 VM             [datastore1] SLES 12 VM/SLES 12 VM.vmx                       sles11_64Guest   vmx-08
/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM # vim-cmd vmsvc/reload 59
/vmfs/volumes/53071ba5-6f9682d4-5898-002590883ef6/SLES 12 VM #

Reboot your machine and try to start your controller it will work.

Thanks 
Nagesh

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue after a BIOS update - the `kvm` module was loaded (& could be removed & re-inserted) - `libvirtd` was crashed with the error 'KVM is not available' - checking `/dev/kvm` it did not exist which is the clue.

The solution in my case on an AMD system was to enable `svm` (virtualization) in the BIOS. I had enabled it before & the BIOS rebooted itself a couple of times after the update & must have reset it back to off (the default).